# In Google Sheets how to count how many items are in an addition

Tags: google-sheets, split, formula, google-sheets-formula, counting

I want to be able to find how many items I'm adding in Google Sheets.

For example, in a cell, I will have this formulae `=10+20+50` and in the next cell, I want to have 3 as there have been three items (10,20,50) that have been added.

Pls note, the formulae if inside on ONE cell and ONE cell ONLY, so I need to be able to count the 'items' in the formulae.

Is there a way?

Comment: Can you add a demo sheet with sharing enabled?

Answer (score 2):

If cell **A1** contains something like:

```
=1+5+8+65+12
```

then in **B1** enter:

```
=len(formulatext(A1))-len(substitute(formulatext(A1),"+",""))+1
```

For example:

[image]

This just counts the number of *"+"* signs in the formula and adds one.

Answer (score 1):

if **A1** is:

[image: 0]

try:

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(FORMULATEXT(A1); "+"))
```

[image: 0]

arrayformula:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(BYROW(IF(SPLIT(BYROW(A1:A5, 
 LAMBDA(x, FORMULATEXT(x))), "=+-*/^()"), 0, ), 
 LAMBDA(x, LEN(JOIN(, x))))))
```

[image]